# Query Error while trying to populate data from Parse into CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, error-handling, uicollectionview

So I am making an app, where the home view will show two sets of collection views. I am trying to filter how the information is sent and distributed into these two collectionviews based on a parameter from the image posted. My app is crashing down with this error.

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Below I'm putting all my code.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class HomeViewController: UIViewController{

    //VAR ARRAYS - LOST
    var userslost = [String: String]()
    var addresslost = [String]()
    var breedlost = [String]()
     var phonelost = [String]()
    var usernameslost = [String]()
    var imageFileslost = [PFFile]()

    //VAR ARRAYS - FOUND
    var usersfound = [String: String]()
    var addressfound = [String]()
    var breedfound = [String]()
    var phonefound = [String]()
    var usernamesfound = [String]()
    var imageFilesfound = [PFFile]()

    //@IBOUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lostView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var lostCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var foundCollectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //QUERY LOST

        let querylost = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        querylost.whereKey("lostfound", equalTo: "lost")
        querylost.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

            if let posts = objects {

                for post in posts {

                    self.addresslost.append(post["address"] as! String)
                    self.breedlost.append(post["breed"] as! String)
                    self.usernameslost.append(self.userslost[post["userid"] as! String]!)
                    self.imageFileslost.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                }
            }
        }

        // QUERY FOUND

        let queryfound = PFQuery(className: "Post")
        queryfound.whereKey("lostfound", equalTo: "found")
        queryfound.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in

            if let posts = objects {

                for post in posts {

                    self.addressfound.append(post["address"] as! String)
                    self.breedfound.append(post["breed"] as! String)
                    self.usernamesfound.append(self.userslost[post["userid"] as! String]!) **--> ERROR IS HERE**
                    self.imageFilesfound.append(post["imageFile"] as! PFFile)

                }
            }

            }


        //TO SHOW DATA

        scrollView.delegate = self
        lostCollectionView.delegate = self
        lostCollectionView.dataSource = self
        foundCollectionView.delegate = self
        foundCollectionView.dataSource = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

// START OF EXTENSIONS FOR COLLECTION VIEWS

extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.lostCollectionView {
            return addresslost.count
            //DUDA #2
        }

        else {
            return addressfound.count
            //DUDA #2
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == self.lostCollectionView {

            let cell: LostCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Lostcell", for: indexPath) as! LostCollectionViewCell

            //TIENES QUE IGUALAR LOS @IBOUTLETS DEL CELL (SPECIFICOS A LOST) Y IGUALARLOS CON EL ARRAY DE PARSE QUE PUEDES ENCONTRAR EN VARS ARRIBA

            cell.adressLostLabel.text = addresslost[indexPath.row]
            cell.breedLostLabel.text = breedlost[indexPath.row]
            cell.phoneLostLabel.text = phonelost[indexPath.row]

            imageFileslost[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

                if let imageData = data {

                    if let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                         cell.postedImage.image = imageToDisplay

                    }
                }
            }


            return cell
        }

        else {

            let cell: FoundCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Foundcell", for: indexPath) as! FoundCollectionViewCell

            cell.adressFoundLabel.text = addressfound[indexPath.row]
            cell.breedFoundLabel.text = breedfound[indexPath.row]
            cell.phoneFoundLabel.text = phonefound[indexPath.row]

            imageFilesfound[indexPath.row].getDataInBackground { (data, error) in

                if let imageData = data {

                    if let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                        cell.postedImage.image = imageToDisplay

                    }

                }

            }

            return cell
        }

    }

}

//SCROLL

extension  HomeViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        print(scrollView)
    }

}
```

Error can be found in this line of code:

```
 self.usernamesfound.append(self.userslost[post["userid"] as! String]!)
```

Comment: Use ! (force unwrapping) very bad, avoid all situations using it. 
as? - recommendation. When there is no value at as! crash occurs.
self.usernamesfound.append(self.userslost[post["userid"] as? String ?? ""] ?? "")
or 
if let value1 = post["userid"] as? String, let value2 = self.userslost[value1] {
self.usernamesfound.append(value2) }

Answer (score 0):

Please insert this in, it should work:

self.usernamesfound.append(self.userslost[post["userid"] as? String]?)